# Can you disable HOTSPOT on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, network, tethering

I would like to disable hotspot as a dropdown option under WiFi settings.
I manage multiple Macs in profile manager and they are set to connect to a our WiFi which is locked down. Users have been able to bypass our network by tethering the Mac to their phones effectively bypassing our firewalls. This is not good seeing as we are a school.

It looks like a massive omission on Apple's part - not allowing one to disable the ability for users to tether the Mac to any phone.

I realize that WiFi can disabled which may resolve this, but I need to connect to our network via WiFi as these are MacBook Air's without wired LAN connections. Can anyone help me figure out some way to disable tethering as an option either using a script or terminal command, or even better, somehow using profile manager?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the students don't have admin rights on the Macs:

Try this...

- Go to **System Preferences**
- **Network**
- **Advanced..** button
- Select the **WiFi** tab
- Require administrator authorization to:

  - [✓] Change networks
- Click **OK** and **Apply**

If all goes as planned, unless logged in as an admin, users cannot join a new network.

---

[image: Network settings]

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the ability to join unknown Wi-Fi network with [Jamf Pro](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-pro/) and the restriction called **Allow connecting to unmanaged Wi-Fi networks**.